# "print_level =-1" doesn't remove all messages

Tags: python, pyminuit, iminuit

I am succeding fiiting a function with iminuit in python but I can't get rid of the message even with "print_level =-1" or "print_level =0".

Here is the minimalist code I use:

```
from iminuit import Minuit
m = Minuit(chi2, alpha=1., beta=0., print_level=-1)
```

it returns:

```
creatFitsFile.py:430: InitialParamWarning: errordef is not given. Default to 1.
m = Minuit(chi2, alpha=1., beta=0., print_level=-1)
creatFitsFile.py:430: InitialParamWarning: Parameter alpha is floating but does not have initial step size. Assume 1.
```

I just want it to be quiet because I fit inside a loop with ~170.000 set of data.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting `pedantic=False` in the parameter list.

Example -

```
from iminuit import Minuit
m = Minuit(chi2, pedantic=False, alpha=1., beta=0., print_level=-1)
```

From the [documentation](http://iminuit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#minuit) -

> pedantic: warns about parameters that do not have initial value or initial error/stepsize set.

From the warnings in your console, seems like it is these warnings that are getting logged, most probably setting `pedantic=False` should fix it.